# Passing item data to PayPal with ActiveMerchant (payments pro)

Tags: ruby, paypal, activemerchant

I'm hoping somebody can help me with this issue that's got me stuck.
I'm using ActiveMerchant in my rails app to process cart transactions with the Paypal gateway.

The transactions are successful, but when I look at the history in my PayPal account, there is no information about the items associated with the transaction. Occasionally, one will come through with the item data, but most of the time, no items show up in the details.

Here's what's happening in my checkout controller:

```
def process_order            
    @items = Array.new      

    @donations.each do |d|
      item = Hash.new        
      item[:name] = d.project.title 
      item[:quantity] = 1
      item[:description] = "Donation from website"
      item[:amount] = (d.pledge.to_i*100).round
      @items << item
    end

    @response = GATEWAY.purchase(price_in_cents, credit_card, purchase_options)
    if @response.success?
      @validTransaction = true
    end
end

private

 def purchase_options      
  {
  :items => @items,      
  :ip => request.remote_ip,
  :billing_address => {
    :name     => params[:first_name],
    :address1 => params[:last_name],
    :city     => params[:city],
    :state    => params[:state],
    :country  => params[:country],
    :zip      => params[:zip]
    }
  }
end

def validate_card
  unless credit_card.valid?
    credit_card.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
      @errors += message + "<br/>"
    end
  end
end

def credit_card
  @credit_card ||= ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard.new(
  :brand               => params[:card_type],
  :number             => params[:card_number],
  :verification_value => params[:card_verification],
  :month              => params[:date][:month],
  :year               => params[:date][:year],
  :first_name         => params[:first_name],
  :last_name          => params[:last_name]
  )
end
```

I think that's all the pertinent stuff there, so if anyone can see why this wouldn't work, it'd be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've had a problem similar to this, and it was because I was passing HTML code into the "description" value (my descriptions store HTML code). I got around it by replacing the HTML-tagged description with my own static one and it worked fine.

You might want to test with more static data to see what is causing the problem specifically, if you haven't fixed the problem already